# How to scrape a hidden React component key using selenium

Tags: reactjs, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a React based website with selenium and python, and i came to a point where, although i can retrieve all that is being 'seen' by Google DevTools Inspector, i am not being able to find the link to the next page i needed to scrape. I could, i guess, do this, in a way where i could click every single button to the next page, although, i was kind of curious to know why selenium has a problem is seeing this particular key and how to workaround this, since i have to build a database and any 'extra' request will add add up exponentially.

[Google DevTools Inspect View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09bHg.png)

As you can see, there is no 'key' or href class anywhere on the tab, but if i look in React DevTools, it is there:

[React DevTools Inspect View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hy6eb.png)

So my question is: is there any way i can retrieve those 'keys'?

Are there any better tools to do this job?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: no react components are visible to selenium only the output of the vdom. is there not a div on the page with an id or class to select that's missing? it's hard to tell from your question what the issue is

Comment: I already uploaded the screenshots so you can understand better, azium.

Comment: are you able to update the react code? if not you'll have to use a traditional xpath selector

Comment: Update it? If i refresh the page, those keys are attached to the Eventlist.. so they will stay there. Is any way i can access those? Thank you!

Comment: I was asking if you can modify the code, but I'm guessing it is not your website. Anyways, the keys as you are noticing are not actually on the dom, so while it's possible to run something similar to what the react dev tools is using inside your selenium code, accessing those JS values are not going to allow you interact with the dom because that stuff is only in memory prioer to rendering the ouput. your best bet is to do some initial trial and error to determine the selector path for the element you want to click

Comment: The selector, as the image shows, doesnt have the link, or the key, in it, right? So.. How can i replicate what ReactDev Tools is showing? I really dont need to interact with the Dom.. i just need those values,which are hrefs to the next step..

Comment: the keys are hrefs? I'm not sure what you want is possible. the dev tools are rendering out the entire app in its own display but obviously rendering the tree differently with all its props including key. the short answer is you can't access the keys from the dom, but if you render the application tree via javascript you can inspect the component tree in. its object form.  you could look at what react-sight does to do this https://github.com/React-Sight/React-Sight

Comment: React Sight is no longer maintained, AFAIK, right? When i google it, it is said to use, instead, the Performance Tab of the Chrome Dev Tools. 
I will dig a bit more into this, though, cause i cant find a way to replicate what the page is doing, inside of those 6k lines of code..